# Sync from dir1 and dir2, and keep the two directory same

Tags: bash, synchronization, rsync

I want to sync from source directory to local directory, I used to use command: `rsync -av /path1/dir1 /path2/dir2` and it will add the contents of dir1 to dir2.

However, I want to keep dir1 and dir2 same. I do not hope someone else can add files to dir2 without using rsync command (Means want to delete other contents that not belongs to dir1 when sync from dir1 to dir2)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html):

```
    --delete                delete files that don’t exist on sender
```

So, the following should work:

```
rsync -av --delete /path1/dir1 /path2/dir2
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your idea. I just tried before, found that below command can work: rsync --delete -r /path1/dir1/. /path2/dir2